# Open port in Window 7 for local client-server development and debugging

Tags: port, tcpip, localhost, debug

I am writing a C# console application for Windows 7 that can send and listen to packets (client or server). Since I only have one computer, I will have to debug and test my code locally.

I first created a **new rule** in **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**, given it a name "Foo" and enable a TCP port of "55000".

I then install telnet on my command prompt. I tried

```
open 127.0.0.1 55000
open localhost 55000
open 192.168.1.122 55000 // my local network IP
```

All return `Could not open connection to the host, on port 55000: Connect failed`.

Comment: run netstat -ano and see if you see a listening port on port 7

Comment: I ran netstat -ano and it seems port 55000 is not even there. But I had already enabled that port on firewall setting..

Comment: This may be dumb but is your C# console app running and accepting connections on 55000 when you try and telnet.

Comment: I am not even using the application now. I simply open the port and try telneting it because it doesn't seem to be there at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 7 is for the echo protocol.  Ports in the first 1024 numbers are reserved for well-known protocols.  If you are doing development, you should use a port in the 49152–65535 range, according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers .

Comment: I repeat the same thing using port 55000 but still give me the exact same result

Comment: Did the netstat command posted by Mark Scrano show that your program is listening on the port?

Comment: no, it's not even listed there on the result table. But I already add and enabled the port..

Comment: isn't superuser part of stackexchange?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant stackoverflow.